# Error Handling Geoprocessing Service in ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, typescript

I am using ArcGIS JavaScript API 4.21 (with TypeScript). [`@arcgis/core/tasks/Geoprocessor`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-Geoprocessor.html) is deprecated since version 4.20. So I am using [`@arcgis/core/rest/geoprocessor`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-rest-geoprocessor.html) instead.

```
import JobInfo from "@arcgis/core/rest/support/JobInfo";
import ParameterValue from "@arcgis/core/rest/support/ParameterValue";

import * as geoprocessor from "@arcgis/core/rest/geoprocessor";

const GEO_PROCESSING_URL = "..."

// ...

async function execute(): Promise<void> {

  const params: { /* ... */ }

  const jobInfo: JobInfo = await geoprocessor.submitJob(
    GEO_PROCESSING_URL,
    params,
  );

  await jobInfo.waitForJobCompletion({
    statusCallback: checkJobStatus,
  });

  const result: ParameterValue = await jobInfo.fetchResultData("output_file");

  console.log(result.value.toJSON().url);

}

function checkJobStatus(jobInfo: JobInfo): void {
  console.log(jobInfo);
}
```

Above code works well as long as there is no error. If an error occurs, I get following error message (URL obfuscated) in the developer console:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): p: {"sourceUrl":"https://..."}
```

How can I handle failed geoprocessing tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `try/catch` if you are using [`async/awaits`](https://javascript.info/async-await#error-handling).

I think that [`@arcgis/core/rest/geoprocessor`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-rest-geoprocessor.html) could use some (more) examples. Hope that this helps someone else.

```
import JobInfo from "@arcgis/core/rest/support/JobInfo";
import ParameterValue from "@arcgis/core/rest/support/ParameterValue";

import GPMessage from "@arcgis/core/rest/support/GPMessage";

// ...

async function execute(): Promise<void> {

  // ...

  try {

    await jobInfo.waitForJobCompletion({
      statusCallback: checkJobStatus,
    });

    const result: ParameterValue = await jobInfo.fetchResultData("output_file");
  
    console.log(result.value.toJSON().url)

  }
  catch(error) {

    (<JobInfo>error).messages.forEach((message: GPMessage) => {
      console.log(message.toJSON())
    })

  }

}

// ...
```