# How to not expose stack trace in geoprocessing service message to client

Tags: geoprocessing-service, arcgis-enterprise

Lets assume the ArcGIS API for JavaScript code from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/417602/error-handling-geoprocessing-service-in-arcgis-javascript-api/417603#417603):

```js
// ...

async function execute(): Promise<void> {
  // ...

  try {

    await jobInfo.waitForJobCompletion({
      statusCallback: checkJobStatus,
    });

    const result: ParameterValue = await jobInfo.fetchResultData("output_file");
  
    console.log(result.value.toJSON().url)

  }
  catch(error) {

    (<JobInfo>error).messages.forEach((message: GPMessage) => {
      console.log(message.toJSON())
    })

  }

}
// ...
```

In case of an error, I get following messages in the console:

[image]

How can I stop ArcGIS Enterprise from exposing internal server information?

Of course, I just can stop logging it to the console ;) but I want to limit anyone from getting access to information about the server's file structure. I'm interested to let users see the error itself though. For example: "ERROR 000523: Unknown coordinate system for output dataset".

I am looking for a way to not expose a stack trace and/or limit what the information ArcGIS Server is providing to any client (**not specific to ArcGIS API for JavaScript** but also Postman, ArcGIS for Python and so on) using the server's REST endpoint.

---

The only solution I can think of is: I could add a layer of abstraction by implementing a proxy web application which will then just forward the error itself to the client (in addition to not having the geoprocessing service published to the public). However, I would like to avoid introducing an additional server component if possible. I am sure there is a configuration for ArcGIS Enterprise I missed... Hence my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to change the Geoprocessing Service log message away from ERROR or INFO to just WARNING or NONE. This way you the service will never return these messages, no matter what client uses them or if a user peeks under the hood.

See the [Show Messages](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/10.8/publish-services/windows/geoprocessing-service-settings-parameters.htm) setting.

Comment: Thank you. That works for me. However, only `None` does not return a stack trace with ArcGIS Enterprise 10.8.1. Hopefully, with the scheduled upgrade to ArcGIS Enterprise 10.9.1, `WARNING` will work too, even if not, it won't be a big deal. I can handle it otherwise. (I went through the settings before... not sure how I missed this... ;) Thanks again!)

Comment: I might be wrong about WARNING not returning Error messages. I thought it worked "down", but it might be working "up", thus inclusive of errors. In terms of 10.9+ I can pretty much guarantee that nothing has changed for this behavior.